# htaccess rewrite to https if not xml file and not containing display in request URI

Tags: xml, string, .htaccess, url-rewriting, contain

How to create a htaccess rewrite rule to https for non xml file request and when the request URI not containing string "*display*"?

I've tried the following but this doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !xml [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !display [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thank you.

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !xml [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !display [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Because it's `AND`and not `OR`